# Where is oraenv located in solaris?

Tags: oracle, solaris

I had a problem recently with oraenv and oratab and finding out where oraenv is located was a bit challenging.

Since it's a question I ask myself often, I wanted to have it here. It may help others.

Answer (score 1):

This is where it's located:

```
myuser@mysolarishost:mydbinstance:/usr/local/bin
> ls -l oraenv
-rwxr-xr-x   1 oracle   root        7012 Jan 11 11:15 oraenv
```

Comment: That's where you installed it, but the path depends on where each site chooses to install it, so it may differ for others.

Comment: @alanc You make a good point but can you expand a bit? I never have an option to pick a location for oraenv. So I would think it would always place it in the local binaries. The binaries location may change however if placed somewhere else? Is that what you mean?